# How I can get the difference by time string and Datetime now?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, datetime, time

i want to calculate a checktime to the time now and get the hours.

I have a string "time" for example...

```
Jun 06 2013 07:23:06
```

and with DateTime.Now I get the Time now. The Problem is now that i can't calculate the difference :(

I need them in my Project where I get from the License Server the time from a user and I want to show the difference to now. I want show this in hours.

Comment: `var difference = DateTime.Parse("Jun 06 2013 07:23:06") - DateTime.Now`

Comment: Whats preventing you from parsing/converting to date and then doing the comparison?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc165448.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `Parse` method of the DateTIme class to parse a string as a date and the subtract that from now.

```
TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Now - DateTime.Parse(dateString);
var hours = diff.Hours
```

The above exsmple of course requires the date to be in a specific format. You can if needed use [DateTIme.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) and specify a specific format yourself

Answer (score 3):

You need to first convert your string to DateTime. here you have custom format so you can use DateTime.ParseExact or DateTime.TryParseExact method as below

```
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact("Jun 06 2013 07:23:06", "MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    // get difference  
    var inDays = (DateTime.Now - dt).Days;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`TimeSpan.Hours`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.hours.aspx) property like;

> Gets the hours component of the time interval represented by the
>   current TimeSpan structure.

```
string dateString = "Jun 06 2013 07:23:06";
var differenceHours = (DateTime.Now - DateTime.Parse(dateString)).Hours;
Console.WriteLine(differenceHours);
```

Here a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/DaSGQI).

If you want to convert your custom formatted string to `DateTime`, you can use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) which need exact format matching between string and datetime.

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   `DateTime` equivalent. **The format of the string representation must
>   match a specified format exactly or an exception is thrown.**

Answer (score 1):

u may try it

```
DataTime diff = DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDataTime(dateString);

var hours = diff.Hours
```